# How to use ctypes void ** pointer in python3

Tags: python, ctypes

I would to connect a spectrometer by its DLL, one of function is defined as

```
UINT UAI_SpectrometerOpen(unsigned int dev, void** handle, unsigned int VID,  unsigned int PID)
```

from document, dev is Specify the index for the spectrometer
handle is Return to the pointer of handle of the spectrometer
VID is Provide specified VID
PID is Provide specified PID
dev, VID, PID are known, but I don't know how to set handle.
my current code is as

```
import ctypes
otoDLL = ctypes.CDLL('UserApplication.dll')
spectrometerOpen = otoDLL.UAI_SpectrometerOpen
spectrometerOpen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(c_void_p),
                         ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint)
spectrometerOpen.restypes = ctypes.c_uint
handle = ctypes.c_void_p
errorCode = spectrometerOpen(0, handle, 1592, 2732)
```

When I run above code, I got error as

```
runfile('C:/Users/Steve/Documents/Python Scripts/otoDLL.py', wdir='C:/Users/Steve/Documents/Python Scripts')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-73fe9922d732>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Steve/Documents/Python Scripts/otoDLL.py', wdir='C:/Users/Steve/Documents/Python Scripts')

  File "C:\Users\Steve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 685, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Steve\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 85, in execfile
    exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Steve/Documents/Python Scripts/otoDLL.py", line 5, in <module>
    spectrometerOpen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(c_void_p),

NameError: name 'c_void_p' is not defined
```

I am not familiar with ctypes and C, can anyone help me to resolve this matter.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error output:

```
  File "C:/Users/Steve/Documents/Python Scripts/otoDLL.py", line 5, in <module>
    spectrometerOpen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(c_void_p),
```

You forget to put `ctypes` before `c_void_p`, thus:

```
spectrometerOpen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),
                         ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint)
```

According to your function signature , the handle parameter is a pointer to a `void*`, thus you need to pass it like this:

```
import ctypes
otoDLL = ctypes.CDLL('UserApplication.dll')
spectrometerOpen = otoDLL.UAI_SpectrometerOpen
spectrometerOpen.argtypes = (ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_void_p),
                         ctypes.c_uint, ctypes.c_uint)
spectrometerOpen.restypes = ctypes.c_uint

# declare HANDLE type, which is a void*
HANDLE = ctypes.c_void_p

# example: declare an instance of HANDLE, set to NULL (0)
my_handle = HANDLE(0)

#pass the handle by reference (works like passing a void**)
errorCode = spectrometerOpen(0, ctypes.byref(my_handle), 1592, 2732)
```

Note: this is just an example, you should check the documentation of the `spectrometerOpen` function to see what exactly it is awaiting exactly for the `handle` parameter (can it be NULL, what type is it exactly, etc.).

Comment: The result type attribute is `restype`, not `restypes`. The default value is `c_int`.

Comment: A well-designed ctypes wrapper should make it extremely difficult to segfault the interpreter. Invalid arguments should be caught beforehand to raise an exception. For stronger type safety you can create a handle type as `class Handle(ctypes.Structure): _fields_ = [('value', ctypes.c_void_p)]`. Set `ctypes.POINTER(Handle)` in `spectrometerOpen.argtypes`. For functions that use the handle just set `Handle` in `argtypes`. This will be a lot less permissive than using `c_void_p` in case a function is called with an invalid argument.