# dereferencing the whole Data of c_void_p not only the first byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, dereference

i have a Question about Pythons ctypes and calling C functions bothering me for a couple days now. I'm working with Python 3.5 and ctypes to wrap a C .dll.

I've got a C Function accepting a `void **` as an output parameter. This should contain a Pointer to some 8 Bit RGB Data of a Image after the Call.

```
foo(void ** bar)
```

I declare my Python parameter and function call as following:

```
>>bar = c_void_p()
>>foo(byref(bar))
```

And try to recieve the Data:

```
>>data = c_byte(bar.value)
>>data.value
20
```

which actually is a reasonable value for the first Pixels 'R'-Byte
But i did not manage to reach any Byte beyond this. For my understandig I now get the value of the first Byte the c_void_p points to(?)

I also tried:

```
>>data = (c_byte*3)(bar.value)
```

3 is only for test purposes (tried and went up to couple thousands):

```
>>data
<__main__.c_byte_Array_3 at 0x7faca45de950> #so far so good again?
>>data[0]
20
>>data[1]
0
...
>>data[n]
0
```

for me it seems like i cant acces any further Bytes again?

when i Try to define `bar` as a int Pointer (what is recommend by a lot of guys) i get the following:

```
>>bar = POINTER(c_int)()
>>foo(byref(bar))
>>bar
<__main__.LP_c_int at 0x7fcf71d9d8c8>  #so far so good?
>>bar.contents
Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I also worked through anything i found online including:
[this](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/828975-question-about-ctypes-function-f-void), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517410/how-to-use-ctypes-void-pointer-in-python3), and a couple more I cant find right now.

Any Help is really appreciated!

**edit:**
whole code of the python file:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes_wrapper_dijsdk import *
init()
guids = find_cameras()
handle = c_void_p()
open_camera(guids, handle, 0)
start_acquisition(handle, 1)
imageHandle = c_void_p()
VOIDPP = POINTER(c_void_p)
imageData = VOIDPP(c_void_p())
get_image(handle, imageHandle, imageData)
byte_buf = cast(imageData.contents, POINTER(c_ubyte * (1920)))
for x in range(0, (1920)-1 ):
 print("value: {:3d}".format(byte_buf.contents[x]))
dimension = (c_int*2)()
get_int_parameter(imageHandle, 0x20000103, dimension, 2)
value = c_void_p()
get_int_parameter(imageHandle, 0x20000200, value)
#from now on would be able to get the ImageData Size
print("ImageFormat = ", value.value, "see SDK.h")
release_image(imageHandle)
close_camera(handle)
exit()
```

call from python to C:

```
def get_image(handle, imageHandle, imageData, timeout = 0):
 return d.SDK_GetImage(handle, byref(imageHandle), imageData, timeout)
```

**additional information:**

- there actually are more `void**` output parameters in the code, such as  `imageHandle`. But they do not address any Arrays and seem to work just fine. They are declared as `c_void_p`and are called `byref( )`.
- the RGB Data stored as a Byte stream of Pixels of each Line. so its dimension[0] x dimension[1] x bit-depth long.
- I can't provide any C Code because it is part of a shared library.

Comment: Not that it would make any difference, but how is the 9bit data stored? Contiguously to save space (as it wouldn't make sense to waste a whole byte for the 8th bit)?

Comment: sry, seems like my head was already at lunch... 8bit obv... corrected it @CristiFati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way of doing things. Also, *ctypes*'s official doc: [[Python 3.5]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

*dll.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#if defined(_WIN32)
#  define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define DLL_EXPORT
#endif

#define C_TAG "From C"
#define PRINT_MSG_0() printf("%s - [%s] (%d) - [%s]\n", C_TAG, __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__)
#define PRINT_ERR_1S(ARG0) printf("%s: %s\n", C_TAG, ARG0)


DLL_EXPORT int test(void **pptr, size_t count) {
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    if (!pptr) {
        PRINT_ERR_1S("NULL pointer received");
        return -1;
    }
    if (*pptr) {
        PRINT_ERR_1S("Non NULL inner pointer received");
        return -2;
    }
    unsigned char *buf = (unsigned char*)malloc(count);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        buf[i] = (i + 1) % 0x100;
    }
    *pptr = buf;
    return 0;
}


DLL_EXPORT void dealloc(void **pptr) {
    PRINT_MSG_0();
    if ((pptr) && (*pptr)) {
        free(*pptr);
        *pptr = NULL;
    }
}
```

*code.py*:

```python
import sys
import math
from ctypes import c_ubyte, c_int, c_size_t, c_void_p, \
    POINTER, CDLL, \
    cast


VoidPtrPtr = POINTER(c_void_p)

dll_dll = CDLL("./dll.dll")
test_func = dll_dll.test
test_func.argtypes = [VoidPtrPtr, c_size_t]
test_func.restype = c_int

dealloc_func = dll_dll.dealloc
dealloc_func.argtypes = [c_void_p]

DISPLAY_VALUES_COUNT = 5
FORMAT_STRING_PAT = "    idx: {{:{:d}d}} - value: {{:3d}}"


def _get_print_indexes(array_size, values_count):
    if array_size <= 0 or values_count <= 1 or values_count > array_size:
        raise ValueError("Invalid args")
    yield 0
    if array_size > 1:
        if values_count > 2:
            interval_size = array_size / (values_count - 1)
            for idx in range(1, values_count - 1):
                yield int(round(idx * interval_size))
        yield array_size - 1


def _print_array_values(array, array_size, values_count=DISPLAY_VALUES_COUNT):
    index_width = math.ceil(math.log10(array_size))
    format_string = FORMAT_STRING_PAT.format(index_width)
    for idx in _get_print_indexes(array_size, values_count):
        print(format_string.format(idx, array.contents.contents[idx]))


def main():
    sizes = [
        10,
        100,
        500,
        1920 * 1080 * 3,
    ]

    for size in sizes:
        UByteArr = c_ubyte * size
        UByteArrPtr = POINTER(UByteArr)
        UByteArrPtrPtr = POINTER(UByteArrPtr)
        print("\nSize: {:d}".format(size))
        data = UByteArrPtrPtr(UByteArrPtr())
        print("data: {:}, data.contents: {:}".format(data, data.contents))
        #print(addressof(data), addressof(data.contents))
        ptr = cast(data, VoidPtrPtr)
        res = test_func(ptr, size)
        if res < 0:
            print("{:s} returned {:d}. Moving on...\n".format(test_func.__name__, res))
            continue
        print("data: {:}, data.contents: {:}".format(data, data.contents))
        _print_array_values(data, size)
        dealloc_func(data)
        print("data: {:}, data.contents: {:}".format(data, data.contents))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- Since the array allocation place (*C* or *Python*) wasn't mentioned, I chose the former option (otherwise, the *double pointer* (`void **`) wouldn't make much sense). This adds some complexity to the code (among other things: `dealloc` - to avoid memory leaks). Using the latter option would "generate" less code, and no need for `void**` (I'm still wondering why it's needed anyway)
- `void*` is a generic type with not very much info. That's why in *C*, in order to populate the individual bytes, I had to *cast* it to `unsigned char *`. Same thing applies to *Python*. The way I expressed `void **` in *Python* is via `POINTER(c_void_p)`
- A lot of the code is for printing purposes. That includes:

  - `_get_print_indexes`, which is only used to select ***5*** (`DISPLAY_VALUES_COUNT`) *equidistant* (from index perspective) elements in an array
  - `_print_array_values` - prints the values

**Output**:

> ```
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051981858>"c:\Install\x86\Microsoft\Visual Studio Community\2015\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051981858>dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051981858>cl /nologo dll.c /DDLL  /link /DLL /OUT:dll.dll
> dll.c
>    Creating library dll.lib and object dll.exp
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051981858>dir /b
> code.py
> dll.c
> dll.dll
> dll.exp
> dll.lib
> dll.obj
>
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q051981858>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
>
> Size: 10
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 object at 0x000001F8189FBBC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 object at 0x000001F8189FBC48>
> From C - [dll.c] (16) - [test]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 object at 0x000001F8189FBBC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 object at 0x000001F8189FBCC8>
>     idx: 0 - value:   1
>     idx: 2 - value:   3
>     idx: 5 - value:   6
>     idx: 8 - value:   9
>     idx: 9 - value:  10
> From C - [dll.c] (35) - [dealloc]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 object at 0x000001F8189FBBC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_10 object at 0x000001F8189FBD48>
>
> Size: 100
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 object at 0x000001F8189FBCC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 object at 0x000001F8189FBDC8>
> From C - [dll.c] (16) - [test]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 object at 0x000001F8189FBCC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 object at 0x000001F8189FBC48>
>     idx:  0 - value:   1
>     idx: 25 - value:  26
>     idx: 50 - value:  51
>     idx: 75 - value:  76
>     idx: 99 - value: 100
> From C - [dll.c] (35) - [dealloc]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 object at 0x000001F8189FBCC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_100 object at 0x000001F8189FBE48>
>
> Size: 500
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_500 object at 0x000001F8189FBC48>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_500 object at 0x000001F8189FBEC8>
> From C - [dll.c] (16) - [test]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_500 object at 0x000001F8189FBC48>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_500 object at 0x000001F8189FBDC8>
>     idx:   0 - value:   1
>     idx: 125 - value: 126
>     idx: 250 - value: 251
>     idx: 375 - value: 120
>     idx: 499 - value: 244
> From C - [dll.c] (35) - [dealloc]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_500 object at 0x000001F8189FBC48>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_500 object at 0x000001F8189FBF48>
>
> Size: 6220800
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_6220800 object at 0x000001F8189FBDC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_6220800 object at 0x000001F818A62048>
> From C - [dll.c] (16) - [test]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_6220800 object at 0x000001F8189FBDC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_6220800 object at 0x000001F8189FBEC8>
>     idx:       0 - value:   1
>     idx: 1555200 - value:   1
>     idx: 3110400 - value:   1
>     idx: 4665600 - value:   1
>     idx: 6220799 - value:   0
> From C - [dll.c] (35) - [dealloc]
> data: <__main__.LP_LP_c_ubyte_Array_6220800 object at 0x000001F8189FBDC8>, data.contents: <__main__.LP_c_ubyte_Array_6220800 object at 0x000001F8189FBEC8>
> ```

***@EDIT0***:

- Cleaned the code a bit (some renames, ...)
- Separated printing (added `_print_array_values`)
- Modified the *ctypes* pointers to be more meaningful. What stands out and can be confusing, is the relationship between a pointer and an array (**when wrapped by another (outer) pointer**):

  - In *C* they are somewhat equivalent: both reference the address of the 1<sup>st</sup> (array) element. Easily *cast* one to another
  - In *Python* the array must be wrapped by `POINTER` (like a *pass by value* type) in order to be *equivalent* to the pointer (and cast from / to it)
- Successfully ran the same code on *Lnx*

Comment: First of all thanks for the Detailed answer! I worked through it and adapted my code as far as possible. But it seems like I still have some bad parts in it.
my declaration looks like this now:
`VOIDPP = POINTER(c_void_p)
imageData = VOIDPP(c_void_p())
get_image(imageData)
byte_buf = cast(imageData.contents, POINTER(c_ubyte * (1920*1080*3)))`
by now: you mentioned that `POINTER(c_void_p)` is the equivalent to `void **`. So isn't it one ptr to much now? Correct me if I'm wrong obv....

if i try to access any value with `byte_buf.contents[n]` I again get SIGSEGV....

Thanks again.

Comment: You have a sharp eye :). Yes it is too much it should have been `POINTER(c_ubyte)`, but then I couldn't index it. So, I used a trick - as in *ctypes* you can't cast (directly) from a pointer to an array: dereferenced the pointer and got a reference to the array's 1st element. That way I am able to index it. I was able to run the code with your size. I also ran it on *Lnx*. what is `n`? It would be easier to post your full code in the question. Also note that I am treating the memory as it as an 1 dimensional array. Is it your case as well? I would need more details on the *C* function.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer and that Tip about ctypes. The sizes varies from camera to camera, so its not that easy, but thats another thing. `n` is basically any number in the array... I just tried with 1920 Byte. My camera right now uses 1920x1080 Pixel with 8 bit-depth RGB colours. So that i get the first third one the first line, for trying purposes. Furthermore I edited the original question to provide you some more info
btw: with `print("value: {:3d}".format(byte_buf.contents[x]))`i dont get any SIGSEV anymore, but only 0s as values...

Comment: I said that I treat the memory as a 1D array. Is this your case (as It could be 3D). Any doc on the module? Is it publicly available? what has changed in the `print`?

Comment: yes it is stored as a 1D Array, sorry. It is only available if you buy a Camera.. so basically no public information. And no possibility to publish it. only informationg given is: "_\param[out] imageData Pointer to the image data for the image" not really helpful. nevermind that, it seems that it only affects "PyCharm" it does work both ways in iPython3