# how to get value in python using by the address of sent from c++?

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, memory-address

In C++, i take a int typed variable and pass it's address to python. The address is hexadecimal and passed to python as string. In the python, I convert it into int type and use ctypes.cast(). But it crashes.

In python,

```
class testClass:
        def testMethod(actorArg, stringArg):
            a = int(stringArg,16)     #stringArg is the hex address in string type
            print(type(a))            #gives int type
            print(ctypes.cast(a, ctypes.py_object).value)    #crashes!
```

The base idea was from this ctypes in python where i did this,

```
import ctypes

s = 10
print(id(s))     #gives the address of s
print(ctypes.cast(id(s), ctypes.py_object).value)   #gives the value from address
```

In short, **I want to get value in python using by the address sent from c++.** Any idea where am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to pass the memory address from one executable (written in c++) to another (written in python)?

Comment: Actually i am working in unreal game engine. There i want to pass a variable's address from C++ to Blueprint to python. I can pass the address to python. But from python, i cant not get the value using the address. Unreal has python build in. 

Besides, what is the matter with ctypes.cast(obj, type). i still dont get it that much.

Comment: This is not possible in general[1]. When applications run in an OS, the OS allocates an "application space" to a process. It is there that you declare arrays, or play around with pointers.  A pointer to a memory location for one application is meaningless for the other application.


[1] - You need a mechanism like `shared memory` or a `pipe` for inter process communications; look up how you can do that for your use case.

Comment: @Roy2511 May be, I didn't understand the OP correctly but he claimed: The python interpreter is embedded. In this case, Python and C++ code are running in the same process. (This is the way we use it in our application.) Passing the address as hex string still appears a bit convoluted to me but it could work in this case.

Comment: Since unreal has python embedded, here do c++ and python use separate memory space? 
If same memory, i need a variable to pass from c++ function to python. But so far i could not do it. So my idea was to pass the memory address from C++ and python could have it and fetch the value using that address. 

Now i can pass the address from c++ to python (as in string type. i have to make hex to string for some reason). I wanted to use that in python to get the value from memory.

Comment: @Scheff I am not sure either. There isn't enough information to go on. To be honest the easiest way is to set up sockets on both sides, pass the value and close the connection.

Comment: @Roy2511 For communication in one process, I wouldn't use sockets. The latter are not easy to handle as well (for me) - beside of the performance impact (compared to just passing values or addresses in arguments). However, I fully agree with _There isn't enough information to go on._ ;-)

Comment: When embedding Python in our C++ application, we started with small samples to get used with the tech. (and its pitfalls). (This has proved as good strategy for anything new we start(ed).) About Unreal Engine, I don't know anything than its name and its purpose. I believe it's a big beast and surely has its own pitfalls. Additionally, there might be something under the hood which prevents you from doing what normally should work. TL;DR: Start with a [mcve]. If you get stuck you have something you can present here. ;-) (The extra effort will definitely pay off -> my experience.)

Comment: Thanks @Scheff i sure will try. :)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.py_object - when you cast the pointer to `py_object`, that expects it to be a `PyObject *`, not a mere `int *`. Indeed, when you write `s = 10` in Python, that is internally an object, not just an `int`. Otherwise read that entire page and see proposed dupe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dereferencing the whole Data of c\_void\_p not only the first byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981858/dereferencing-the-whole-data-of-c-void-p-not-only-the-first-byte)

Comment: thank you @tevemadar To be honest, i am really a beginner. I understand your point about pyobject pointer. But to be honest, the possible duplicate answer was way above my head.

Answer (score 0):

If `a` is the correct address of a C integer in the same process, then you want:

```
value = ctypes.c_int.from_address(a)
```

Your second code works with `s` because `s` is a *Python* integer, not a *C* integer, and `id(s)` (on *CPython* at least, as an implementation detail), returns the address of the Python object.

Comment: I get c_long(0). I have checked the C++ code. I initialized  an integer there and passed the address to python in string format. The address is in C++ is  000000EC6AEC9B58 and in python it is same.

Comment: @arafat Update your question with reproducible code. This is the correct code **if** the address is correct and it is the same process.

Comment: @arafat Also, is the variable still in scope? Again a reproducible example of the attempted code would help.